# change icon on click using css or ngClass only

Tags: css, html, angular, font-awesome

Hy guys, I was trying to change icon on click, but I found only examples with jquery. I was wondering if it's possible using only css or ngClass since I'm working in an Angular project. I'm using font-awesome 5 and Bootstrap 4. Below is the code that I wrote in trying to achieve my goal.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" #password1 class="col-md-9 form-control" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password">
    <div class="input-group-append" (click)="changeType(password1, 1)">
      <span class="input-group-text" [ngClass]="toggle1 ? 'fas fa-eye' : 'fas fa-eye-slash'"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="c_password" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Password Confirmation</label>
    <input type="password" name="c_password" id="c_password" #password2 class="col-md-9 form-control" placeholder="Repeat Password" [(ngModel)]="c_password">
    <div class="input-group-append" (click)="changeType(password2, 2)">
      <span class="input-group-text" [ngClass]="toggle2 ? 'fas fa-eye' : 'fas fa-eye-slash'"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
toggle1: boolean = false;
toggle2: boolean = false;

changeType(password, num){
  if(password.type=="password")
    password.type = "text";
  else
    password.type = "password";

  if(num == 1)
    this.toggle1 = !this.toggle1;
  else
    this.toggle2 = !this.toggle2;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to change the icon on the click and change the type of parameter passed to the function to show the password just written.

Comment: Can't you use `ngIf` and have 2 elements, one for each icon?

Comment: If possible I would prefer using ngClass or css as I wrote. If there aren't other ways, then I'll try your method

Comment: try `[ngClass]="{'fas fa-eye':toggle2 , 'fas fa-eye-slash':!toggle2 }"`

Comment: @Gabax is it help?(look at comment above...)

Comment: It works like before. When I click the the span, the eye-slash turns into a blank square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5pmn3r?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

**UPDATE**

Use in this way,

```
<span class="input-group-text"><i [ngClass]="toggle2 ? 'fa fa-eye' : 'fa fa-eye-slash'"></i></span>
```

Comment: sorry but I don't see the spans with icons so it's not testable

Comment: @Gabax check now. I forget to save after adding bootstrap and font-awesome. sorry.

Comment: What have you changed? I don't see differences with my code but the class **fas** turns into **fa**

Comment: I used font-awesome 4.7, that's the main difference.

Comment: But I would like using font-awesome 5. What do I have to change? I installed this to used the free icons: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts

Comment: @Gabax see updated answer also I updated example. If it solves your problem, please select it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks it works. In the end, my error was using span tag instead of the tags

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you just a sample with using `css`. hope it'll help you.

### html

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

### css

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:before {
    content: url('http://placekitten.com/200/210');
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    content: url('http://placekitten.com/210/220');
}
```

Comment: Do I have to put the tag input inside the other tag input?

Comment: no need to do like that, you can run this sample of code directly.